# Compare two R Dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

I have two R dataframes (which are the output of a prediction algorithm) filled with 1s, 0s, and -1s, and I would like to compare them row wise, to see how similar they are in the sense that how many values per row are identical.

This is an example of what they would look like:

```
  var1 var2 var3
  1     1    0
  -1    0    -1

  var1 var2 var3
  -1     1    0
    1    0     1
```

What I would like, is a metric that tells me that:

```
        Identical
 row 1   2/3
 row 2   1/3
```

Comment: `rowMeans(df1 == df2)` ?

Comment: Son of a b.... that is brilliantly simple!! love it!! Thanks David

Comment: I did not think of that at all.